# Very simple blend function in fragment shader take too much time

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, shader, blending

I'm loading two or more textures into fragment shader then blend them with blend functions.

The blend function I'm using is very simple, say "normal blend mode", the function is

```
lowp vec4 blend_normal(lowp vec4 base, lowp vec4 blend)
{
    return base * (1.0 - blend.a) + blend * blend.a;
}
```

But even this simple, it increase my gpu render time up about 30ms. If I don't use the blend function, it takes about 15ms to render, if I add this blend function, it takes about 45ms, on my iphone5s.

I must have done something wrong. Please give me some advice.

Comment: This is [mix](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/mix.xhtml) have you tried using it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick comment, but I have other blend function too, they can't all be replaced by mix

Comment: But it is same as mix(base,blend,blend.a) isn't it?

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with what you did. Where are you testing that and what does your original shader look like? If you are doing more or less nothing in your shader than adding this function will easily add 200% computation time to it.